# AWS Lightsail custom domain not registered to account

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, dns

I created a deployment on AWS lightrail. I tried to add a custom domain, but on the "custom domains" tab i see that the domain is "not registered to account". The domain was purchased on another website. What do I need to do in order to reach the deployment under my custom domain.

Comment: There's really no reason that you have to use Lightsail to manage the DNS records for your domain. You could just create the DNS record over on whatever service you are currently using to manage your domain.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by [Creating a static IP and attach it to an instance in Amazon Lightsail | Lightsail Documentation](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/lightsail-create-static-ip). This will ensure that the IP address does not change.

Then, create an `A-Record` on the site where you purchased the domain. Configure the A-Record to point to the Elastic IP address you added to the Lightsail instance.

This assumes that you just want to point the domain name to single computer.

Comment: how can I attach a static ip to a running container?